# XmlImport One Line Table Not Pulling (Using VBA)

Tags: excel, xml, vba

VBA is not fetching the headers of an XML table when the table only has one line.  Is there a way to fix this?  I'm using:

```
ActiveWorkbook.XmlImport url:=url, ImportMap:=Nothing, Overwrite:=True, Destination:=Worksheets("A").Range("A1")
```

Comment: Please share a reproducible sample (specifically the value of `url` if public, or a sample data if not).

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8a5d3990-e17b-4f18-b338-8172720a6d23/ms-excel-doesnt-show-column-headers-if-xml-contains-1-record?forum=excel

Comment: If XML contains just one record, Excel places header and data side bu side. This is a know bug. You can use this solution: http://ashuvba.blogspot.com/2014/07/exporting-single-recordset-from-xml-to.html